# AngularJS: select is not updating the HTML view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select

I've encountered a problem about the AngularJS's ***select option*** tag.

I'm trying to pass the `completeStatus` values to **AngularJS**'s **select** tag, to use them in a dropdown list from **Java**. Looks like it is working fine. The problem is, when I select a value from that list, it is not updating the **HTML** side, and showing me the selected one.

I don't think it is related to the code I've written already, because of it is filling the list correctly. I think it can be related to the built-in functions of Angular.

#### Below one is my HTML side of code:

```
<div class="quick-search-inpage">
<label class="item item-stacked">
    <select class="select" id="completed2" name="completed2" style="width: 160px"
        ux-select data-ng-model="parentScope.userReportListFilter.completeStatus">
        <option value="">Tamamlanma Durumu</option>
        <option value="COMPLETED">Tamamladı</option>
        <option value="NOT_COMPLETED">Tamamlamadı</option>
        <option value="CONTINUE">Devam Ediyor</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Since I am passing values from Java, there are no any variable or value about `userReportListFilter.completeStatus` in my **JS** code. (And as I said, it is working fine and filling up the dropdown list)

When I inspect element of that dropdown list, I'm seeing that it's state is not updating itself to ***ng-dirty***.

I've checked some questions in SO, but couldn't find a similar one to my question.

EDIT:

Selecting value from dropdown list:

[image]

Selected value shown in the list:

[image]

Even though I've selected ***Tamamlandı*** from the list, I am still seeing ***Tamamlanma Durumu*** in the menu. So we can say that dropdown list is now showing the selected option.

Comment: You shouldn't use ng-options and option tag at the same time

Comment: That was forgotton there, I've updated the code. Problem occured while I am only using **option** in the code.

Comment: I think the problem is related on your controller structure. As you can see in this fiddle it does work fine http://jsfiddle.net/du08ofgd/ - so please add the part where you try to set `parentScope.userReportListFilter.completeStatus`.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no need to set `parentScope.userReportListFilter.completeStatus` . If you delete Angular part of your code from your fiddle, you will see that dropdown list is still working fine (reflecting the selected data on the screen).

Comment: I cant get ya. what is your problem so? Could you create a plnkr or fiddle please?

Comment: I am not able to create plnkr or fiddle, because code is working in there. So I've updated the question with screenshots.

Comment: Well m8, we are not able to fix your problem if you are unable to deliver the code parts we need. please create a simple fiddle to reproduce your problem. It seems like you using some UI helper stuff. So please take some time and create a fiddle. Else I dont think we are able to help ya.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144362/discussion-between-prometheus-and-lin).

Comment: where did you set parentScope in your html template ? Do you have a ng-controller or controllerAs somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wants to know the answer, I was using "***templates***" to split up the **HTML** codes. When I moved my template the regular HTML code, it fixed the problem. I believe possible reason for problem is, like they stated in the comments, external library.